# Issues with relative paths in PHP includes

Tags: php, css, path

Before going on, I'd just like to say that I've tried pretty much everything, and I read a lot of questions here at Stackoverflow, but none of the solutions worked.

So here is the deal, I have a file ("empresaConf.php") that contains this code:

```
<?php
    include 'navigator2.php';
?>

<div class="contTudo">

    <div id="bgCorpo">

    <div class="empresaConf">

        <?php
            include 'sqEsqInc.php'
        ?>

    </div>

    </div>    

<?php 
    include '../rodape.php';
?>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it is including "rodape.php". The problem is that in "rodape.php", I have an image that is in another folder, so when I include "rodape.php" in "empresaConf.php", the image path should change, since PHP include consider the file path to be the one that you're including other files, making rodape.php's image broken when I access "empresaConf". I want something to fix that so I have the image no matter what file I'm in. Here is the "rodape.php" code:

```
<div class="empresa">

            /* below in the img src tag you can see what I'm talking about */
            <div class="redeSocial">
                <a href="http://www.facebook.com.br">
                    <img src="imgs/icons/iconFace42.png" class="iconeFace">
                </a>
            </div>

</div>  <!-- Fim div .empresa -->
```

The folder structure is: "rodape.php" is in the root directory and "empresaConf.php" is inside a folder named "Empresa" (I would post a img but I can't).

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Sorry, I forgot a crucial detail, I'm also including "rodape.php" in other files such as "index.php". So if I change the img src to correspond "empresaConf.php", then in the "index.php" the image will be broken, since it's in the root directory, same as "rodape.php".

Comment: I generally use an absolute path for everything in PHP, using the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` env var.

Comment: syntax-speaking; you're missing a semi-colon `include 'sqEsqInc.php'`

Comment: yes, put the semi colon at the end like fred suggested. if problem is still there let use know

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible, so let's try to resume it: My problem is that from the "rodape.php" point of view, the img path is "/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png", but when I include the "rodape.php" in the "empresaConf.php" file, the img path should change because I'm now working at "/empresa/empresaConf.php", so the img src should be "../imgs/icons/iconFace42.png". How can I define that the path is different for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an image accessible from the public side of things, the image can probably be accessed by the directory root. So if your index.php is in `/index.php` where `/` is the web document root and your image is in `/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png` you can access the image by

```
    <img src="/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png" class="iconeFace">
```

Note the leading slash in the src attribute.

Comment: That would make sense, but when I try to do that, the image is broken both in "empresaConf" and "index". The thing is, from the "rodape.php" point of view, the img path is that one, but when I include it in "empresaConf.php", the img path should change because I'm now working at "/empresa/empresaConf.php", so the img src should be "../imgs/icons/iconFace42.png". How can I define that the path is different for each file?

Comment: Are the files at `domain.com/index.php` and then `domain.com/empresa/empresaConf.php` ? If so, this should work, otherwise, you have to include all the subdirecotries `<img src="/path/to/dir/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png" class="iconeFace">`

Comment: Yes that's exactly their paths. What do you mean by include all the subdirectories? I thought the root directory was the last one possible.

Comment: If you were developing a site where you were not developing the main page for the domain, for example `domain.com/mysite` and your index and images are at `mysite/index.php`  and `mysite/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png`, then you would have to include the `/mysite/` sub directory

Comment: The website is not online yet, I'm working with EasyPHP. Do you think that has something to do with it?

"empresaConf.php" path = "http://localhost/projects/TCC_07-06_G/empresa/empresaConf.php"

"index.php" path = "http://localhost/projects/TCC_07-06_G/index.php"

Comment: Yeah, your file is looking at `localhost/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png` when the file is actually at `localhost/projects/TCC_07-06G/imgs/icons/iconFace42.png` so you need to include the full path.

Comment: Well, I found a "hack" that allowed me to use a variable to the img src via JS, so I guess my problem is solved. I was thinking that I might encounter other problems realated with variable paths, but that's for another day. Really thank you for trying to help me (I don't know the etiquette, do I need to upvote you or something?).

Comment: If my answer got you to the answer, then mark it accepted. If another answer is better, mark that. Either way, you should make it so the next person with a similar question can see what you had to do.

Answer (score 0):

You have some options.
If rodape.php will only be accesed from that folder level, simply change the src to `../imgs/icons/iconFace42.png`, if you will be changing folder deep then use an absolute path to the image. Another way would be add php code to set the src but that would be wast of resources.

Answer (score 0):

When you include `../rodape.php`, think of it like just putting the code from that file directly in the position where it was included. The path string will not change, as it has not been executed until it has been included.

In short, that is to say, things will be relative to the file that's being executed, not the file(s) that's being included.

```
<img src="../imgs/icons/iconFace42.png" class="iconeFace"
```

Using that image code should resolve your issues.

Comment: Yes, I tried to do that, I forgot to tell that I'm including rodape.php in other files, so that won't work. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using a non-relative path, like http://yoursite.com/img/icons/iconFace42.png ?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question (English is not my native language), but I'm using EasyPHP to "host" the application, since it's not online yet. I want to define that the img src path is different in each file that I include the "rodape.php".